# Navbar not responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The navbar does not get smaller when viewing on phone.
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Urt6.jpg "Example"

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top text-uppercase bg-inverse" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img style="height: 80px;" src="img/logobanner.png" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Foto's</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio2">Agenda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Boeken</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

When you view on phone you can scroll right and there is nothing but white space and the hamburger menu.
Maybe i forgot to add a class or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you refering bootstraps js, jquery etc? If not add them to the end of the body. Did it on my end and it works.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

It doesn't have any styling but you should get the point: https://jsfiddle.net/enstL6j7/1/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top text-uppercase bg-inverse" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img style="height: 80px;" src="img/logobanner.png" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Foto's</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio2">Agenda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Boeken</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think there were some problem with the cdn. Try not to use jquery slim version as sometimes it may cause problems.